# ??? Error using ==> plus Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles

Tags: matlab, int, double

When i'm trying to add pixel data to data created by gaussian `randn()` function it's spitting the error

> ??? Error using ==> plus Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

This is my code:

```
im = imread( 'ngc6543a.jpg' );   % matlab example image
x  = randn( size (im) );         % create gaussian distributed values
t  = im + x;                     % add them together, this throws the error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the integers (uint8) from your read image `im` to double:

```
t = double(im) + x;
```