# Matlab Enframe Integers can Only be Combined with Integers of The Same Class

Tags: matlab, integer, scalar, uint

I am new to MatLab, and I realize this question is already asked around so much, and I have checked some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300588/error-using-plus-integers-can-only-be-combined-with-integers-of-the-same) and [there](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66733-error-integers-can-only-be-combined-with-integers-of-the-same-class-or-scalar-doubles-when-processi), but none of it seems working on my case.

I opened a wav file and tried to convert it to the frequency domain:

```
[y,fs,wmode,fidx]=readwav('sound.wav','r',-1,0)
left = y(:,1)
```

And then viewed the figure:

```
plot(left)
figure
spgrambw(left,16000)
```

However I get the said error when I tried to create frame with:

```
frames = enframe(left, uint16(length(left)/6))
```

I've tried:

```
[1] enframe(double(left), uint16(length(left)/6))

[2] uint = uint16(length(left)/6)
    enframe(double(left), uint)
```

Both still returned Integers can Only be Combined error. left is a matrix 48000 X 1. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the 2nd argument to enframe() to uint16? Most matlab functions expect double arguments.

Comment: I think it needs to be: `frames = enframe(left, floor(length(left)/6))`. You can also do: `frames = enframe(left, double(uint16(length(left)/6)))`, but it makes no sense.

Comment: yes I changed the uint16 to double and now it"s working... I think it is because the size of the matrix? And uint16 can not accomodate it?